# peewee.DataError: string or blob too big, How to increase `DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER` in peewee?

Tags: python, sql, binary, peewee

I would like to store 1.5 GB of binary data in SQLite DB using peewee ORM. 
I get `peewee.DataError: string or blob too big`. Can I somehow change the limit in peewee?

How to increase `DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER` in peewee?

Comment: I hit a similar error `OverflowError: BLOB longer than INT_MAX bytes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your question, "How to increase DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER in peewee?" -- this is a compile-time option so you'd need to recompile SQLite and specify a new value. I don't think that this is the correct compile-time option for your issue, however.

I'd like to suggest that this is an absurdly big "binary blob" to be storing in SQLite. You may be bumping up against the SQLite maximum length of a blob/string: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length -- to alter this you would need to recompile SQLite specifying the new desired maximum value.

For very large blobs you can also look into using the SQLite blob file-like APIs, which are supported by Peewee (though their usage is a fairly niche topic and you'll need to read the SQLite docs to get a good understanding of how it works): http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/sqlite_ext.html#sqlite-blob

Lastly, what would be wrong with just leaving the BLOB on the filesystem (which is good at storing large files) and just referencing the filename from your database?